# Получение Bitmap из ImageView с задержкой

Tags: java, android, jsoup, bitmap

Есть ImageView `img`, в которое картинка загружается по ссылке при помощи Picasso:

```
ImageView img = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
Picasso.get().load(Uri.parse(currentNews.getmImg())).into(img);
```

Сама ссылка парсится с помощью Jsoup.

Проблема в том, что в момент выполнения кода

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)img.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

картинка не успевает загрузиться, и приложение крашится с логом

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference

Как можно обойти эту проблему более "лаконично"? Установить задержку выполнения получения Bitmap через `Handler.postDelay`?

Весь код выполняется в адаптере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таких целей у Picasso есть `callback`

```
Picasso.with(this)
   .load(url)
   .into(img, new Callback() {

         @Override
         public void onSuccess() {

         }

         @Override
         public void onError() {

         }
    }
);
```

Comment: Спасибо, не знал.